# Getting "Maximum nesting level exceeded" error when wrap a recursive stored procedure in another procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, stored-procedures

I have a recursive procedure "FindLoopMakingNode" which is used to find loops, and I'm not expecting nested level to be more than 30.

Here is the recursive procedure:

```sql
alter procedure FindLoopMakingNode
@p1 int,
@p2 nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    -- recursively calls itself
end
```

Also, I have another procedure "CheckFormulaForLoop" which is responsible for finding every kind of loop and it uses the recursive procedure mentioned above as well as other statements.

Here is the main wrapper

```sql
alter procedure CheckFormulaForLoop
@p1 int,
@p2 nvarchar(max),
@p3 bit
as
begin
   --search for other kinds of loop
   --if no other loop exists calls recursive procedure
   EXEC dbo.FindLoopMakingNode @p1,@p2
   --writes the result in a temp table which has been created by wrapper procedure
end
```

Because I use the second proc for different scenarios, I have different wrapper procedures which use it

Here is the problem: when I execute "CheckFormulaForLoop" for a given set of parameters there is no problem but when I execute one of those wrapper procedures for the exact same set of parameters, I get the Error blew:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Here is the wrapper(the one which throws exception, and yes, it's really that simple)

```sql
alter procedure CheckFormulaForLoopWrapper
@p1 int,
@p2 nvarchar(max),
@p3 bit
as
begin
   Create table #tempLoopHolder(id int,code int)
   EXEC CheckFormulaForLoop @p1,@p2,@p3
   SELECT id,code from #tempLoopHolder
end
```

Now when I run

```sql
 Execute CheckFormulaForLoopWrapper 1212,'2',1
```

It throws the exception but when I run

```sql
Create table #tempLoopHolder(id int,code int)
EXEC CheckFormulaForLoop 1212,'2',1
SELECT id,code from #tempLoopHolder
```

it runs successfully

I'm wondering if there is a problem with recursion levels why sql doesn't throw an exception when running the main procedure? and can nesting be responsible for this error?

Comment: I suppose the question is, do you *need* nesting in your SP?

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like its nesting 32 times when you run it outside the wrapper, and therefore running 33 times inside the wrapper which exceeds the limit.

Comment: Just put a trace select or print in and count it to debug it and check that its nesting the correct number of time or whether there is an issue.

Comment: "I'm not expecting nested level to be more than 30" - Well, I guess that's SQL Server's way of saying "surprise!" recursion is something that's usually easy to write but hard to execute, and very easy to write wrong. I would suggest to try and avoid writing recursive anything in SQL.

Comment: @Zohar Peled : Yes, and it gets very harder since I'm a c# developer and this is the first experience of writing complicated sql queries.

Comment: @Larnu ,If you mean recursion could be skipped, Well I could put the recursive part in C# code and just do the checking in storeProcedure but that way I was facing another problem which was too many requests to sql server. (That was the first thing I tried and we had a hard time trying to make the performance better and then we came up with the idea of putting all the code in a store procedure)

Comment: Just to get clearer , just first procedure is recursive "FindLoopMakingNode" , I mean isn't recursion level measured just on this particular SP?how wrapping can effect levels?

Comment: The wrapper procedure adds another nesting level. In SQL Server, a procedure is considered nested when it's called by another procedure. As you can surly understand from the error message, using a stored procedure recursively is probably not the best way to handle whatever situation you need handling. If the soul purpose of this procedure is to fill a temporary table, there are probably better ways to do that then recursion. You might want to ask a different question on how to implement whatever it is that procedure does in a set based approach (which is SQL's strong suit).

Comment: @Zohar Peled ,Thank you very much for this very useful sentence:  "The wrapper procedure adds another nesting level. In SQL Server, a procedure is considered nested when it's called by another procedure". This was almost the answer I was looking for. And No the purpose of procedure is not filling a temporary table , that table is a way to share data among involved procedures. Actually we have some tree-structured data in which every node gets its value by a formula and that formula is consist of values of other nodes so we have to make sure that there is no loop in formulas

Comment: First, I'm glad I can help. Second, as I wrote before, your best option is to replace the recursive stored procedure with a set based one. If you can create a [mcve] that will contain sample data as  [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and desired results (meaning, the same result you would get from your recursive procedure, or at least something that you can translate later to your one algorithm) - that would probably be a question well worth answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to thank all of you for your precious helps

using all your tips, I found That using a combination of nested procedures + recursive procedure is my problem since as @Zohar Peled said :

> The wrapper procedure adds another nesting level. In SQL Server, a procedure is considered nested when it's called by another procedure. As you can surly understand from the error message, using a stored procedure recursively is probably not the best way to handle whatever situation you need handling. If the soul purpose of this procedure is to fill a temporary table, there are probably better ways to do that then recursion. You might want to ask a different question on how to implement whatever it is that procedure does in a set based approach (which is SQL's strong suit).

I used  @@NESTLEVEL that @Dale Burrell had mentioned and it turned out that my recursive procedure had to run 31 times (for given parameters) and this amount + 2 ( for 2 wrappers) led to the exception

So finally I see no way to fix it but trying to find a set based approach instead of recursion

Answer (score 0):

You may maintain this by adding one more parameter to keep the count of recursive call.

You can pass a parameter and before executing your procedure check the value, in your case `<30`. For true condition before executing your procedure increment your value by `+1`. By this way you can keep the track of how many times your `recursive` call is made.

Sample code for same will be like this

```
Create proc Calltab  ( @id int, @cou int=0 )
as
Begin
    if(@cou <30 )
    Begin
        --- perform your operation in this section
        set @cou = @cou + 1   --- here increment your value by +1 for the count
        exec CallTab @id, @cou
    end
end
GO
```

You may test the same with this

```
exec CallTab 1 , 0
```

Comment: Or, rather than re-inventing the wheel, use [@@NESTLEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nestlevel-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)